# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() error

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, model, adapter

ModelOrderUser.java

```
package my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.models;

public class ModelOrderUser {
    String orderId,orderTime,orderStatus,orderCost,orderBy,orderTo;

    public ModelOrderUser(){

    }

    public ModelOrderUser(String orderId, String orderTime, String orderStatus, String orderCost, String orderBy, String orderTo) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.orderTime = orderTime;
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
        this.orderCost = orderCost;
        this.orderBy = orderBy;
        this.orderTo = orderTo;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getOrderTime() {
        return orderTime;
    }

    public void setOrderTime(String orderTime) {
        this.orderTime = orderTime;
    }

    public String getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }

    public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }

    public String getOrderCost() {
        return orderCost;
    }

    public void setOrderCost(String orderCost) {
        this.orderCost = orderCost;
    }

    public String getOrderBy() {
        return orderBy;
    }

    public void setOrderBy(String orderBy) {
        this.orderBy = orderBy;
    }

    public String getOrderTo() {
        return orderTo;
    }

    public void setOrderTo(String orderTo) {
        this.orderTo = orderTo;
    }
}
```

AdapterOrderUser.java

```
package my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.R;
import my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.models.ModelOrderUser;

public class AdapterOrderUser extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterOrderUser.HolderOrderUser>{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ModelOrderUser> orderUserList;

    public AdapterOrderUser(Context context, ArrayList<ModelOrderUser> orderUserList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.orderUserList = orderUserList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolderOrderUser onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflate layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_order_user,parent,false);
        return new HolderOrderUser(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderOrderUser holder, int position) {
        //get data
        ModelOrderUser modelOrderUser=orderUserList.get(position);
        String orderId = modelOrderUser.getOrderId();
        String orderBy = modelOrderUser.getOrderBy();
        String orderCost = modelOrderUser.getOrderCost();
        String orderStatus = modelOrderUser.getOrderStatus();
        String orderTime = modelOrderUser.getOrderTime();
        String orderTo = modelOrderUser.getOrderTo();

        //get shop info
        loadShopInfo(modelOrderUser,holder);

        //set data
        holder.amountTv.setText("Amount: ₹" +orderCost);
        holder.statusTv.setText(orderStatus);
        holder.orderIdTv.setText("OrderID:"+orderId);
        // change order status text color
        if(orderStatus.equals("In Progress")){
            holder.statusTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
        else if(orderStatus.equals("Completed")){
            holder.statusTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
        }
        else if(orderStatus.equals("Cancelled")){
            holder.statusTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
        }
        
        //convert timestamp to proper format
        Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(orderTime));
        String formatedDate= DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyy",calendar).toString();

        holder.dateTv.setText(formatedDate);

    }

    private void loadShopInfo(ModelOrderUser modelOrderUser, final HolderOrderUser holder) {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        ref.child(modelOrderUser.getOrderTo())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String shopName =""+dataSnapshot.child("shopName").getValue();
                        holder.shopNameTv.setText(shopName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderUserList.size();
    }

    //view holder class
    class HolderOrderUser extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView orderIdTv,dateTv,shopNameTv,amountTv,statusTv;

        public HolderOrderUser(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //init views of layout
            orderIdTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderIdTv);
            dateTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTv);
            shopNameTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopNameTv);
            amountTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.amountTv);
            statusTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusTv);

        }
    }
}
```

I am facing the following while executing don't know what is happening

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(DatabaseReference.java:96)
      at my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.adapters.AdapterOrderUser.loadShopInfo(AdapterOrderUser.java:84)
      at my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.adapters.AdapterOrderUser.onBindViewHolder(AdapterOrderUser.java:56)
      at my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.adapters.AdapterOrderUser.onBindViewHolder(AdapterOrderUser.java:26)
```

Please help me out with this error

don't know why the code is throwing errors for me
please help me out

I am getting errors in lines number 84,56,26

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: Line 84, 56 , 26

Comment: Please Help me out with this error

Comment: It should be only one line. Besides that, we cannot see what is at that line. Please add the corresponding code to your question.